# jQuery Slider using .load - Possible use for delegate()

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a website that loads each page using jQuerys .load function which is all working fine.

The issue I have is that a slider on one of the pages doesnt work when loaded in, whereas if written on the main document itself it works correctly. As I understand when using .load certain aspects don't work correctly and the need for `delegate()` comes in.

What I can't work out is how to turn this jQuery into something that will work on each page:

```
// jQuery Slider Script
$("#navi ul").tabs("#panes > div", {
    effect: 'fade',
    fadeOutSpeed: 500,
    rotate: true
}).slideshow({
    autoplay: true,
    interval: 6000
});
```

I have tried using both `delegate()` and `live()` but haven't managed to get it working.

Any help would be great!

Thanks :)

Comment: may this help? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Comment: @Joe - it must be late.. good spot, thank you ;) Edited the post

Comment: May be that your script is in document ready. Happend that once the DOM is ready to be manipulated you're calling an external script that references to some elements (DIVs etc...) from the main page. ** Maybe if you put a call to the external file into a `$(window).load(function(){` that may help ! ?! :)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of messing, I finally solved it.

Adding the jQuery code to slider file that was being loaded solved the issue.

Sorry for a noob question!

Answer (score 0):

put the javascript inside a

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(


)
</script>
```

Comment: I am yeah. As I say it all works fine if its written on the main index.php page, but the second its included and brought in using .load it doesnt work any more

Comment: you need to bind it to the element. .live() works for events... Use '$("#navi ul").unbind();` and then your Jquery code... to bind it to the element (the ul). And load the your code in each AJAX request in the .load() function.

Comment: Could you possibly give me an example of that please? I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of your code, it seems like the problem is that you need to do this:

```
$("#navi ul").tabs("#panes > div", {
    effect: 'fade',
    fadeOutSpeed: 500,
    rotate: true
}).slideshow({
    autoplay: true,
    interval: 6000
});
```

Within the callback function of your .load event.
http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function() {
  alert('Callback code here.');
});
```